# Circular dependencies when field injection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I thought using @Autowired on fields (field injection) does the spring boot application free of the circular dependencies. But after migration our app from Spring boot 1.1.7 to 1.3.3 I encountered exception regarding circular dependencies. @Lazy on the fields helps but there are too many places where I should do that.. So maybe you know what can be a reason?

Comment: It's hard to help without any code. Generally, circullar dependencies indicate that there is a problem with the architecture. `@Autowired` doesn't magically resolve them. There is a number of tools to generate dependency diagrams for Spring. These diagrams should help track this kind of problems. IDE support is also nice in this matter (IntelliJ, Eclipse, Spring Tool Suite).

Comment: Lazy loading should help to resolve them. I can't change architecture of 8 years programm